# Why are with TPH inheritance default values ignored?

Tags: entity-framework

```
CREATE TABLE Lodging
(
     LodgingID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
     LodgingName nvarchar(100),
     IsResort bit NOT NULL,
     ResortChainOwner nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
         ...
)
```

`Lodging` DB table maps to `Lodging` entity. I've then implemented a TPH inheritance:

• With `Lodging` entity being the base

• I've created a new entity `Resort`, which derives from `Lodging` entity.

• I moved resort-specific property `ResortChainOwner` to the `Resort` entity type and also set ( in SSDL ) `ResortChainOwner's` Default Value to "`notApplicable`"

• Lodging table's `IsResort` column is a discriminatory column. If `IsResort` column contains `0`, then record is materialized into `Lodging` entity and if column contains `1`, then record is materialized into `Resort` entity

When in the following code `SaveChanges` is called, EF should supply (to an insert command) a default value for `ResortChainOwner` field, but instead it supplies a `Null`

```
var lodging = new Lodging();
...
context.Lodgings.AddObject(lodging);
context.SaveChanges();
```

So how do I on inserts force EF to supply a default value for `ResortChainOwner` column?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR default value from the SSDL is used when the property is not mapped in the CSDL and the column in the database is not nullable. In this scenario without the default value no insert would ever succeed.